# Squeeze theorem for $n^{1/n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

We are required to use the sandwich/squeeze theorem to find the following limit :
$$\lim_{n \hspace{0.1cm}\to \hspace{0.1cm} \infty} n^{1/n} \hspace{0.5cm}\forall \hspace{0.3cm} n \in \mathbb{N}$$

The sequence that is lesser than the above sequence can be easily identified as $1^{1/n}$

I am stuck with the sequence to be found for the right part of the inequality.

I saw in a Youtube video that this same question was asked but they had provided in the question itself that the student may use the following inequality without proof :
$$n^{1/n} < 1 + 2\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}$$

It is quite easy to prove after this that the the given sequence converges to $1$ as n gets larger and larger.

1. I am interested in proving the given equality
2. I am looking for any other sequence that could be used to fill in the inequality

Till now what I have done for problems like this is as follows. I require a greater sequence than $n^{1/n}$. So what I think immediately is that I must either increase the base n or decrease the n in the power so overall the sequence will be greater.

Increasing the base from n to $n^n$ doesn't help here. Decreasing the power n to 1 doesn't help either since in both cases we get n as the resultant sequence which is far from converging to $1$

Edit : The first question was answered (thanks to Martin R for the link) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/710955/42969,%20math.stackexchange.com/q/1436663/42969)

Still looking for hints to my second question . . .

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/710955/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1436663/42969

Comment: Found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24n%5E%7B1%2Fn%7D%20%3C%201%20%2B%202%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%7D%7D%24)

Comment: More proofs of that limit here: [How to show that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/115822/42969)